# MVVMCross dynamically construct generic IMvxLog<T> for dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvmcross

I'm trying to get Mvx to work in the same way that Microsoft Logging works e.g. `ILogger<T>` via injection but getting stuck.

I've extended the interface:

```
public interface IMvxLog<T> : IMvxLog {

}
```

In my LoginViewModel I want to inject this:

```
public LoginViewModel(IMvxLog<LoginViewModel> loggger) { }
```

And then I figured I could dynamically construct by using the below in App.cs:

```
var logProvider = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxLogProvider>();
Mvx.IoCProvider.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton(typeof(IMvxLog<>), () => logProvider.GetLogFor<>());
```

It doesn't work as I don't have a type argument to pass to the delegation.

`Using the generic method group 'GetLogFor' requires 1 type arguments`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing there is not allowed, the way Mvx can register these kind of injections is by using open generics `typeof(IFoo<>)`.

You can do what you want by just wrapping the provider `GetLogFor` in the `MvxLog<T>` implementation and calls the same methods inside:

```cs
public interface IMvxLog<T> : IMvxLog
{
}

public class MvxLog<T> : IMvxLog<T>
{
    private readonly IMvxLog _logImplementation;

    public MvxLog(IMvxLogProvider provider)
    {
        _logImplementation = provider.GetLogFor<T>();
    }

    public bool IsLogLevelEnabled(MvxLogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return _logImplementation.IsLogLevelEnabled(logLevel);
    }

    public bool Log(MvxLogLevel logLevel, Func<string> messageFunc, Exception exception = null, params object[] formatParameters)
    {
        return _logImplementation.Log(logLevel, messageFunc, exception, formatParameters);
    }
}
```

and then you just register it:

```cs
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType(typeof(IMvxLog<>), typeof(MvxLog<>));
```

and use it like:

```cs
public LoginViewModel(IMvxLog<LoginViewModel> loggger) 
{ 
    _logger = logger;    
}
```

HIH